# Setting selected elements in a BaseElementSelectorModal (or BaseElementIndex)

Tags: plugin-development, garnish

I'm writing a Javascript based plugin which creates an instance of `Craft.BaseElementSelectorModal`.

When the modal is created, I'd like to have some of the entries in the modal's element index auto-selected (i.e. their containers should have the `sel` class added, just like when the user actually selects an entry). I have an array of entry IDs to work with, but I'm struggling to find a way to actually set the element index' selected entries.

As far as I can tell, there aren't any parameters I can set to the `BaseElementSelectorModal` (aside from `disabledElementIds`, which I can't use as I don't actually want the entries to be *disabled*, only *selected*).

I can get to the modal's BaseElementIndex instance – is there a way to programmatically select an array of entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much exploring in craft.js, I've concluded that this can't be done in a clean way.

However, I found a workaround which seems to do the trick.

First, here's (a simplified version of) the code that creates the modal (which is stored in the variable `modal`):

```
var modal = new Craft.BaseElementSelectorModal('Entry', {
    criteria: criteria,
    onSelect: onElementSelect
});
```

After creating the modal, I use `setInterval` to look up the `modal.elementIndex` property. The reason I use a poller is that this property is actually `null` until the internal AJAX call to `actions/elementIndex/getElements` is completed. Anyway, I poll the `elementIndex` property every 10ms, until the property is found (or after 5 seconds have passed, when its safe to assume something has gone awry).

Finally, the element index' method `selectElementAfterUpdate` is used to select the entries. The method only takes a single entry ID, so I have to call it once for every entry ID in the `entryIds` array.

```
var pollCount = 0;
var pollInterval = 10;

var poller = setInterval(function () {
    pollCount++;
    if (pollInterval * pollCount >= 5000) clearInterval(poller);
    if (modal.elementIndex)
    {
        clearInterval(poller);
        $.map(entryIds, function (entryId) {
            modal.elementIndex.selectElementAfterUpdate(entryId);
        });
    }
}, pollInterval);
```

Not very smooth! But it works.